# Get Previous Page of ViewPager on ListView Scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ViewPager inside ListView Item. On ListView scroll I wanted to get my previous page which I have Selected in ViewPager.

I have tried to set the position into

```
vPager.setTag(position)
```

But not getting the way to retrieve my previous page`

Here is My getView() of ListView

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup vGroup) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vRow=view;
    final ContentHolder holder;
    if(view==null){

        holder=new ContentHolder();

        vRow=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_swipe_view_pager, null);
        holder.vPager=(ViewPager) vRow.findViewById(R.id.ui_pager);
        holder.radiogrp=(RadioGroup) vRow.findViewById(R.id.ui_radiogroup);
        int pageCount=integer.length;
        addRadio=new AddRadioViewSwipe(context, pageCount);
        addRadio.addRadio(holder.radiogrp);
        try{
            holder.radiogrp.getChildAt(0).setAlpha(1.0f);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("loop", "error"+e);
        }
        vRow.setTag(holder);

    }
    else{

        holder=(ContentHolder) vRow.getTag();

    }
    ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdpt=new ViewPagerAdapter(context, integer,R.layout.activity_viewpager_model);
    holder.vPager.setAdapter(pagerAdpt);
    holder.vPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    holder.vPager.setTag(position);
    holder.vPager.setPageMargin(-150);
    holder.vPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d("pos", ""+position);
            if(holder.vPager.isShown()){

            }
            for(int i=0;i<integer.length;i++){
                holder.radiogrp.getChildAt(integer.length-(i+1)).setAlpha(0.5f);

            }                   
            holder.radiogrp.getChildAt(position).setAlpha(1.0f);
            Log.d("pos", ""+position+"");   
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {
            Log.d("t1", ""+position);

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            Log.d("t1...", ""+arg0);
        }
    });
    return vRow;
}
```

Comment: Post some sample code, please. I can't understand your question clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked For me:

```
Parcelable state=holder.vPager.onSaveInstanceState();

holder.vPager.setAdapter(pagerAdpt);

holder.vPager.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```